# I would like to use jqGrid to load the following json object. How do I do this?

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

I would like to use jqGrid to load the following json object. How do I do this?

```
{"cell":
 [[
  {"address":"usa","age":22,"id":1,"laptop":"yes","name":"ram","salary":12234},
  {"address":"xyz,","age":25,"id":6,"laptop":"yes","name":"abc ","salary":23889}
 ]]
}
```

This is what i have tried. I have tried it without using jsonmap. I m unable to find the mistake. Please someone help me.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#datatable").jqGrid({
    url:"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/employeesList",
    datatype:"json",
    mtype: "GET",
    colNames:["address","age","id","laptop","name","salary"],
    colModel:[
                {name:"address",index:"address",jsonmap:" cell.address", width:60},
                {name:"age",index:"age", width:90,jsonmap:" cell.age",},
                {name:"id",index:"id", width:100,jsonmap:" cell.id",},
                {name:"laptop",index:"laptop", width:80, align:"right",jsonmap:" cell.laptop",},
                {name:"name",index:"name", width:80, align:"right",jsonmap:" cell.name",},      
                {name:"salary",index:"salary", width:80,align:"right",jsonmap:" cell.salary",}      
            ],  
            rownumbers: true,
            rownumWidth: 40,
            gridview: true,
            jsonReader : {
                root: "rows",
                page: "page",
                total: "total",
                records: "records",  
                repeatitems: false,
               },     
            caption: "Data"
});
});
```

Controller Part

```
  public @ResponseBody JSONObject listEmployees() {
        Map<String, Object> modelMap = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 
  modelMap.put("employees",
  prepareListofBean(employeeService.listEmployeess()));
          JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            JSONArray jsonarray=new JSONArray();
           for (Entry<String, Object> entry : modelMap.entrySet())
        {
            String key = entry.getKey();
           Object value = entry.getValue();
             jsonarray.add(value);
         }
        json.put("cell", jsonarray);
       return json;
      }
```

Comment: Which **version** of jqGrid you use (can use) and from which **fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? Why you return the `cell` value as **array of array** (`[[ ...]]` instead of `[[ ...]]`)? Why you use `"cell"` as the root element, instead of default `"rows"`? You use `root: "rows"` inside of `jsonReader`.

Comment: You should **remove** all `jsonmap` properties from `colModel` after fixing the format of server response. You should remove unneeded `index` properties too. Additionally, the response from the server don't contain any paging information. Thus I suppose that the returned data is the full data and not only one page of data. Thus you should add `loadonce: true` option.

Comment: free jqGrid. "Why you return the cell value as array of array ([[ ...]] instead of [[ ...]])?" that is because my controller is returning jsonobject in that format.

Comment: cell is a key. " json.put("cell", jsonarray);"  jsonarray consists of data retrieved from Database. And I m returning json object

Comment: Which **version** of free jqGrid you use? I recommend you to change the code of your controller to return more correct data. I'm sure that the data will be prepared **specially for jqGrid**. Then it's better to change the code of controller. It's better to return just array of items. See [here](https://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/014-post-json-to-spring-rest-webservice/#json-to-java-arraylist) an example. You could required to use `produces = "application/json"` attribute explicitly

Comment: 4.1. I tried returning Hashmap. But i m not sure of how to use jqGrid for it.

Comment: First of all jqGrid 4.1 is more as 6.5 years old. It's good for museum, but not for usage with modern web browsers. "jqGrid" as the product exist till the version 4.7. After that there are two main forks under the names ["free jqGrid"](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), which I develop, and *commercial* ["Guriddo jqGrid JS"](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334), which develop Tony Tomov. You should update to free jqGrid 4.15.0 or to Guriddo jqGrid JS 5.2.1. If you have any problem to read JSON data, then you should include *the latest* test JSON data, which returns your controller.

Comment: Sorry its 4.14.1.  I have included the Controller part.

Comment: I don't use Spring myself. It should be very simple to return any data in any format. One should never convert the data manually (like in `JSONObject` in your current code). Look at [here](http://www.jcombat.com/tips-and-tricks/convert-json-to-hashmap-and-hashmap-to-json) or search in Internet. You can post **separate** question if you have problem to return JSON data.